# How to get past the 5000 row limit in a SQL Server Reporting Services tablix report?

Tags: ssrs

I have a report whose data returned exceeds 5000 rows in a tablix in SSRS 2012. When I Google this, I get all kinds of info concerning settings in Sharepoint, but this instance is running in Native mode, so Sharepoint is not involved. There is a List View Threshold setting in Sharepoint, but I can't find a reference to this in SSRS only. Also, I would prefer to increase or disable this limit per report and not for the whole instance. Is this possible? Or does SSRS simply have a hard limit of 5000 rows?

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to have nothing to do with the Microsoft side at all. The data source we are using is a linked server to Proficy Historian and, by default, only pulls 5000 rows. You have to explicitly tell it either how many rows you want to pull, or tell it RowCount = 0 for unlimited rows. Sorry for the noise!

[How To Set Rowcount in Historian OLE DB SQL Query](http://support.ge-ip.com/support/index?page=kbchannel&id=09237d4900112023fa71400691e)